# Intel Threading Building Blocks support for Intel Xeon Phi Co-Processor

Tags: versioning, intel, tbb, xeon-phi

I have asked this on the Intel's forums, with no luck.

Does anybody know in which version of Intel TBB did they start supporting the Xeon Phi co-Processors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial support was added in Intel(R) TBB 4.1.

Comment: I never said I intended to use older versions. I was preparing a lecture of Shared Memory Programming, and I wanted to highlight the fact that TBB has not always supported such said architecture. I appreciate your reply, however, can you provide me with a reference to it?

Comment: If you download Intel TBB 4.1 and 4.0 U5 packages for Linux from [Intel TBB open source site](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/download#stable-releases) and extract them you will notice that 4.1 version has binaries for Intel Xeon Phi but 4.0 U5 version does not.

Comment: To tell the truth it is a rather obvious fact that Intel TBB has not always supported Intel Xeon Phi since Intel TBB was inroduced on August 29, 2006 ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threading_Building_Blocks)) but the first version of Intel MIC architecture was introduced in 2010 ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MIC))

Comment: As Xeon Phi is an x86 platform, it is curious why anyone would assert that TBB from 2006, which certainly supported x86 at that time, could not - at least in principle, once some build system issues were addressed - run on Xeon Phi.

Comment: Undoubtedly, you can build (possibly with fixes) and run on Intel Xeon Phi any version of Intel TBB. However, if you want to state that it is supported on a specific platform you need to test on this platform. Does anyone test old versions of software on a new hardware? In my opinion, usually current version of software is tested on a new platforms. Therefore, I can suppose that nobody has tested versions before 2010 on Intel Xeon Phi.